# Making a Dataflow block that retains the most recent message by key

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm building a processing pipeline using TPL Dataflow. I feed items into the pipeline, and then each item moves through the pipeline independently, as it bounces from block to block, and is eventually emitted at the end. This pipeline is really more of a network, since each item can take a slightly different path through it.

At some point, though, I want to display a graphical preview of each item in the UI, which should update itself as items are moving through the pipeline. For example, imagine that the items are starships, and I want to render the status of each starship's shields and remaining photon torpedoes (yes, I have been re-watching DS9 lately). For example, my screen might look something like this:

```
Defiant:    72% shields, 10 Quantum
Enterprise: 98% shields, 25 Photon
```

Naturally, shields and torpedoes can be depleted independently, and it can happen for many reasons. If I have a block that handles UI rendering, it will be spammed with messages all the time, for example:

```
Defiant:    80% shields, 12 Quantum
Enterprise: 100% shields, 30 Photon
Defiant:    79% shields, 12 Quantum
Defiant:    79% shields, 11 Quantum
Defiant:    79% shields, 10 Quantum
Enterprise: 98% shields, 30 Photon
Enterprise: 98% shields, 29 Photon
...
```

What I would like to do is make a block that aggregates all these messages by ship name. This way, when the UI block chooses to consume a message (which will happen relatively rarely), it won't receive the entire combat history for each ship, but only its most recent status.

So, what's the best way to write a block like that ? I wrote a quick and dirty version, but I'm not really happy with it:

```
   public class KeyedBroadcastBlock<TKey, T> 
      : IPropagatorBlock<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>, KeyValuePair<TKey, T>>, IReceivableSourceBlock<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>>
   {
      private readonly IDictionary<TKey, T> itemsMap;
      ...    
      public KeyedBroadcastBlock()
      {
         itemsMap = new Dictionary<TKey, T>();
         inputBlock = new ActionBlock<KeyValuePair<TKey,T>>(
            kvp =>
            {
               lock (itemsMap) {
                  bool valueExists = itemsMap.ContainsKey(kvp.Key);
                  itemsMap[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                  if (!valueExists) {
                     midBlock.Post(kvp.Key);
                  }
               }               
            });
         midBlock = new ActionBlock<TKey>(
            key =>
            {
               lock (itemsMap) {
                  T value;
                  if (itemsMap.TryGetValue(key, out value)) {
                     itemsMap.Remove(key);
                     outputBlock.Post(new KeyValuePair<TKey, T>(key, value));
                  }
               }
            });
         outputBlock = new BufferBlock<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>>();

         inputBlock.Completion.ContinueWith(delegate
            {
               midBlock.Complete();
               outputBlock.Complete();
            });
      }

      public bool TryReceive(Predicate<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>> filter, out KeyValuePair<TKey, T> item)
      {
         return outputBlock.TryReceive(filter, out item);
      }

      public bool TryReceiveAll(out IList<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>> items)
      {
         return outputBlock.TryReceiveAll(out items);
      }
   ...
   }
```

(EDIT: cleaned up the code for demonstration purposes)